# Ubuntu 22.04 & Qt 6.5 : qt.qpa.plugin Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt6, ubuntu-22.04

As I installed `Ubuntu 22.04` and `Qt 6.5.2`, I encountered an error that prevented any of my projects from running, and it did not display the output as expected.

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even
> though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt
> platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may
> fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: vnc, minimal, wayland-egl, offscreen,
> xcb, vkkhrdisplay, eglfs, minimalegl, linuxfb, wayland.

[image]

I checked the `/home/username/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/` path and underestand that all files were correct.

[image]

I also try:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/username/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/
```

But it didnt help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To Fix this issue I add QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1 in run section  Build Environment

[image]

This helps me to log and see what actually happens.

from this

```
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/home/parisa/build-untitled1-Desktop_Qt_6_5_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/platforms" ...
qt.core.library: "/home/parisa/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" cannot load: Cannot load library /home/parisa/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
qt.core.plugin.loader: QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/parisa/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/parisa/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I underestand I need to install libxcb-cursor

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-cursor0
```

Note that this happens only in Qt 6.5 above I didnt have this problem before.

Comment: Kudos for this explanation, also on the details how you debug the log.

Comment: This is pretty bad as I updated my Qt SDK installation with the updater tool and after that Qt Creator didn't start anymore. Installing `libxcb-cursor0` fixed the problem.

Comment: @juzzlin Yeah, this issue will happen in Ubuntu. I tested Fedora too, but I didn't have any problems.