# QApplication launched through GDB cannot connect to XServer on WSL2

Tags: c++, qt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 WSL image from WSL1 to WSL2.

In WSL1, I was able to use QTCreator's debugger (a wrapper around GDB) just fine. But after upgrading to WSL2, it now crashes once it reaches the constructor of QApplication().

Here is a basic example that crashes:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv); 
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is a stacktrace. I installed the `libqt5core5a-dbgsym` package, but this appears to make no difference in the stacktrace. If you know how to get debug symbols to work in this environment without re-compiling all of QT, please let me know!

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff0b7bbc0 (LWP 31883)):
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
        set = {__val = {0 <repeats 12 times>, 228, 140737488338864, 140737488338864, 7758946189198844672}}
        pid = <optimized out>
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00007ffff5397859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x7fffffffc058, sa_sigaction = 0x7fffffffc058}, sa_mask = {__val = {140737488339488, 140737488339496, 140737354022076, 140737488338896, 140737354046956, 3, 140737312309764, 0, 7758946189198844672, 140737488339032, 140737322294875, 3, 140737488339032, 140737488339520, 140737312310041, 0}}, sa_flags = 1318150912, sa_restorer = 0x7ffff61a1e5b}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x00007ffff57ebaad in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff5dcd7ae in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff5dce708 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff59f2f55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff5dd0543 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff640b3bd in QApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x000055555555917f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe718) at /mnt/c/source/myProject/main.cpp:105
        rc = 0
        a = <incomplete type>
        args = {_vptr.CLfxArgs = 0x0, m_threads = 0, m_autoFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_firstFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_fragDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_forceFirst = false, m_materialsDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_meshFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_vmFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_logFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_lfxLog = false, m_testNum = 0, m_iterNum = 0, m_batch = false, m_noInit = false, m_qstarFile = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}, m_fragFuncNum = 42076, m_workingDir = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x7ffff5582510}}
        pTest = 0x0
        dAccumTime = 0
        batch = false
        szMsg = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x0}
```

Running a normal debug build works perfectly fine, everything behaves as expected. It **only crashes in the debugger**.

EDIT: If I attach GDB to the running process, I can move past the QApplication constructor just fine. If I try to start the application normally with GDB, I get an error similar to one that happens if the X-server cannot be found:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.


Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
```

I properly exported a DISPLAY variable based on /etc/resolv.conf  which works for the sake of launching QTCreator. So why GDB doesn't like it, I don't know.

EDIT: Further logs, if I enabled QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/c/build/ubuntu20wsl/debug/myProject
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/mnt/c/build/ubuntu20wsl/debug/myProject/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

If I set the variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen`, then GDB *does* make it past the creation of the QApplication. However, the app's window never appears.

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` does not seem to help, and the XServer we use (X410) explicitly recommends against it, and it has caused problems for us in the past if set.

Some other posts on similar issues mention the package `libxcb-cursor0`, but I already have that. (version 0.1.1-4ubuntu1). I also have `libxcb-xinerama0`.

Just in case, I also checked the contents of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms` and they are `libqeglfs.so  libqlinuxfb.so  libqminimal.so  libqminimalegl.so  libqoffscreen.so  libqvnc.so  libqxcb.so`. So the X platform seems to be present, not missing.

- QT version: 5.12.8
- GCC version: 9.2 (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1)
- Ubuntu: 20.04
- QTCreator: 4.11.0
- X410: 3.3.1

Current kit: [image]

Comment: Time toget debug version of library. Are you on wayland or X11? `QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()` parses environment and commandline , but path it takes is dependant on them. Something with environment might be gone wrong. Here it is, on line 1394 : https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qguiapplication.cpp.html

Comment: X11. I'm using X410 as my XServer of choice. How would I get the debug version of QT working? I installed `libqt5core5a-dbgsym` but it has made no difference. I did look at the source for createPlatformIntegration(), but I can't tell at a glance what the problem could be.

Comment: After installing `dbgsym`, sick apport-retrace on your crashdump. Tbh, I think somethignwent wrong with upgrade, maybe even corrupted libarary or package somewhere.

Comment: I have not used apport-retrace before. I'm a bit lost. What exactly do I pass it? Do I just literally copy the stack trace from before into a text file and pass it that way?

Comment: it needs apport trace report.. sorry,I never did this with gdb and naked core dump (we usually retrace remote runs). I would try to run program directly from gdb and see what happens. Having library's source code apointed in .gdbinit helps to let it see which line it is on.

Comment: I was not able to run directly from GDB, I got some weird error that looked to be similar to when the XServer isn't found. But I could attach GDB to it after starting it using the PID. That works fine and gets past the QApplication constructor. So it appears to be a QTCreator-specific problem.

Comment: Ah, that error is when console doesn't get authorisation (essentially it cannot connect becuase it doesn't know what session auth is). Typical for Ubuntu distro. Can be fixed, QT-Creator's issue likely is similar but on different level. It relaces environment by its own. Essentially it sends trash to the program.

Comment: Could it be related to how Qt Creator was installed?Might be issue with configuration conflict after upgrade (if it was literally an upgrade). I used to receive all weird things with Compiz, QtQuick, VsCode etc after upgrades on Ubuntu.

Comment: QTcreator was just installed via Apt, qt5-default, qtcreator, etc. As for the error, it is the following:

(gdb) qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Since this is WSL2, DISPLAY should currently be based on what is in resolv.conf, which is what I exported.

Comment: Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76802978/9484913,you need to install `sudo apt-get install libxcb-cursor0`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R As stated in the post, I already have that.

Comment: Do you have the option to install a fresh WSL 2 instance, and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem when I try to use qtcreator in the docker(also ubuntu 20.04). It shows the similar error info like yours. After doing research, I ran the command in my local PC and it works for me:

```
xhost +local:
```

However, it is not recommended because it opens up your X server to connections from any local user, effectively disabling access control. This command allows any local user to connect to your X server without restriction, which poses security risks. Please make sure this command is secure for your situation before running it.

Comment: This does not work for me unfortunately, I get the same errors as before. `qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.`