# Cannot start Qt app in Docker on Windows with XServer running

Tags: windows, docker, qt

My host is Windows 10 22H2.

I'm new to Docker. I installed and started [XServer](https://scicomp.aalto.fi/triton/quickstart/installxonwindows/) on Windows, but yet when I run `docker run --rm -it -e -DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0 -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 myapp` as recommended in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1651467/running-a-qt-gui-application-in-docker-on-windows) post, I still get the error below. What can be the problem?

**error**

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ws/install/myapp/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
root@772204fed0fb:/home/ws# exit
```

Comment: I have a problem related to `xcb` here is [my question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76802977/9484913) but I use Ubuntu and do not relate to docker I think you need to install dependency. maybe `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1` helps you.

Comment: 1. Avoid running as root. Some GUI apps outright refuse to run as root for security reasons. 2. Can you run other X apps, ie. is this X problem or Qt problem?